# Ambiguïté des énumérations ?

Tags: grammaire, coordination

En discutant avec quelqu'un, celui-ci à fait une blague sur une ambiguïté de ma phrase. C'est anodin mais je me suis demandé si j'aurais pu formulé ma phrase de telle façon qu'elle puisse ne pas être ambiguë, notamment à l'écrit.

Passons aux exemples:

> Il aime l'Asie, et sa femme aussi.

Il me semble que dans ce cas, on ne peut pas savoir de manière sûre si on dit:

- qu'il a deux amours: l’Asie et sa femme
- que lui et sa femme aiment l’Asie.

Ce genre de cas m'a fait penser à l'*Oxford comma* des Anglais qui, il me semble sert à résoudre des ambiguités sur les énumérations e.g.:

> Il y avait mes deux frères, Paul et Jean

Il y a deux personnes, mes deux frères, qui s'appellent Paul et Jean

> Il y avait mes deux frères, Paul, et Jean

Il y a maintenant 4 personnes dont: mes deux frères (non nommés) + Paul + Jean.

Seulement, dans le cas de la femme et de l'Asie, l'ambiguïté demeure il me semble que la virgule soit là ou non.

---

Encore plus simple:

> Il aime l'Asie autant que sa femme.

On ne sait pas s'il compare l'Asie et sa femme (A), ou qu'ils partagent l'amour de l'Asie (B).
Certains cas plus triviaux seront compris dans chacune des situations:

> Il aime le chocolat autant que la vanille (cas A)
>   Il le sport autant que son père (cas B)

Je me demande donc si dans les cas cités, l’ambiguïté est bien réelle, et donc l'interprétation repose plus sur la compréhension et le contexte que sur des règles. Y a-t-il quelque chose que l'on puisse faire pour diminuer l'ambiguïté (sans reformuler complètement, sinon oui, je devrais m'en sortir)

Comment: Ce que vous demandez n'est pas clair : qu'est-ce que vous appelez "sans reformuler complètement" ? Si vous autorisez seulement de modifier la ponctuation, il semble qu'il n'y a rien à faire (il n'y a qu'un petit nombre de phrases que vous pouvez obtenir de cette manière et aucune ne convient). Si vous autorisez de petits changements de formulation, c'est facile "Lui et sa femme aiment l'Asie" / "Il aime l'Asie autant qu'il aime sa femme."

Comment: L'exemple donné, en tout cas, ne relève pas du Oxford comma, pour laquelle il faut trois choses. En générale, en français, on n'énumère pas en disant: les chats, les chiens et les lapins. On dirait **plutôt**: les chats et les chiens ainsi que les lapins, justement pour éviter: A, B, et C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

À propos de la *virgule d’Oxford (Oxford comma)*, son degré d’implantation en français est à peu près nul, et si je comprends bien son usage en anglais, je ne ferais pas la transition interlinguistique si je la rencontrais en français.

À l’oral, on peut habituellement bien résoudre la signification de l’exemple des deux frères :

> Il y avait mes deux frères, Paul et Jean.

Le type de transition entre *« frères »* et *« Paul »*, ainsi qu’entre *« Paul »* et *« Jean »*, une combinaison complexe des variations du ton, ascendant ou descendant, et de la période de pause entre deux items, suffira le plus souvent à lever l’ambiguïté, du moins dans l’espace linguistique régional de la personne qui parle. Bien entendu, d’aucuns aiment à jouer à ne percevoir que la mauvaise interprétation, mais il s’agit selon moi d’un amusement davantage que d’une réelle incompréhension.

À l’écrit, par contre, beaucoup de l’expressivité se perd, et en effet, la phrase est polysémique. Les poètes et les humoristes (et sans doute aussi les politiciens, qui n’aiment pas toujours sceller leurs opinions dans une déclaration) recherchent souvent ce genre d’effet, mais les juristes, au contraire, cherchent à l’éliminer afin de ne donner qu’aussi peu de prise que possible à une interprétation personnelle.

---

Je suppose qu’à l’instar de l’exemple des deux frères, la première phrase citée...

> *Il aime l'Asie, et sa femme aussi.*

...ne relève pas du discours légal.

À l’oral, un accent particulier, un renforcement du ton, sur le mot *« femme »* nous indiquera qu’il aime l’Asie et qu’il aime aussi sa femme *(peut-être visite-t-il l’Asie dans le cadre de son travail, et que sa femme ne l’accompagne jamais là-bas...).* Transférez cette emphase sur le mot *« aussi »*, et nous saurons qu’il partage avec sa femme son amour de l’Asie.

À l’écrit, la phrase me semble, sous cette forme, inextricablement indécidable. Le contexte, bien sûr, devrait pouvoir clarifier *(à moins que ce ne soit le but de l’exercice de demeurer flou quant à la signification du discours)*, mais sorti de son contexte, ça peut vouloir dire deux choses.

Comment: Merci! C'est développé et clair! Bien sûr dans le cas réel de ma situation tout le monde avais bien compris, grâce au contexte et au bon sens. Effectivement, on peut s'amuser sur le ton de l'humour à ne pas faire celui qui ne comprends pas, ce qui montre que la phrase de base n'est pas ambigüe (sinon le second degré aurait été prit pour une incompréhension). Bref, ça a just piqué ma curiosité, merci.

Comment: Etant donné la stylistique en français, ce n'est que très rarement que l'on trouverait la  necessité d'une "virgule Oxford".

Comment: @Lambie Je ne sais pas. Je me suis habitué à sa présence en anglais, quoique ce fut difficile au début, mon esprit étant trop tourné au français. Puis j'en suis venu à l'apprécier pour ce qu'elle est, mais n'ai jamais transféré ou même eu idée de transférer ce type de structure en français. Peut-être, comme vous le laissez entendre, ne serait-elle utile qu'en de très rares circonstances.

Comment: Juste une petite remarque hors propos principal: _légiste_ fait généralement référence au médecin qui pratique les autopsies. Pour parler de quelqu'un qui travaille avec la loi, on parle plutôt de _juriste_.

Comment: @mouviciel J'ai pris en compte votre avis et modifié afin de lever toute ambiguïté *(ce qui demeure dans le ton de la question)*, mais je crois bien que l'un ou l'autre eût été correct: [légiste](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/l%C3%A9giste) et [juriste](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/juriste) au TLFi. Merci de votre remarque.

Comment: Est la virgule après "frères" vraiment exigé?

Comment: @aeismail Certains poètes, Apollinaire par exemple, ont laissé de côté toute ponctuation et composé des poèmes très compréhensibles *(Sous le pont Mirabeau* en serait un bel exemple). Sinon, en ce cas particulier, on aurait pu comprendre, en enlevant la virgule, qu'étaient présents mes deux frères avec le même prénom *(Paul)*, ainsi que Jean. Si l'un des Paul était par exemple Paul-Henry et le second Paul-Émile, peut-être cela pourrait-il demeurer compréhensible, si le fait est connu de l'interlocuteur, mais c'est un cas très particulier qui ne surviendra qu'avec une extrême rareté...

Answer (score 1):

Sans reformuler il me semble impossible de faire disparaître l'ambiguïté, sauf dans le cas des frères. Si je veux nommer mes frères alors je peux utiliser les deux points:

> Il y avait mes deux frères : Paul et Jean

Mais ça ne marche pas avec l'Asie et sa femme.

Dans ce cas, on peut imaginer l'une des deux propositions suivantes :

> Il aime et l'Asie et sa femme.

ou

> Lui et sa femme aiment l'Asie.

L'autre façon de lever l'ambiguïté est le contexte, soit des explications supplémentaires soit des indices non verbaux.

Answer (score 1):

**A mon humble avis,**

> Il aime l'Asie, et sa femme aussi.

ne fait preuve de presque aucune ambiguïté. Ponctuée de cette façon, il aime l'Asie, et sa femme aussi aime l'Asie.

L'exemple qui devient plus intéressant, c'est celui ci :

> Il aime l'Asie autant que sa femme.

Je ne vois aucune autre solution que : le contexte. Rien d'autre ne vous aidera à vous faire comprendre par votre interlocuteur que les phrases qui entourent celle ci.

Comment: Merci! Je suis d'accord que le premier semble mieux capturer l'intention de la personne qui écris. La construction en elle même reste très ambigüe, un cas pire encore serait
> Il aime son fils, et sa femme aussi
Où j'ai plus envie d'entendre qu'il aime les deux (fils et femme), et non que les deux (lui et femme) aiment le fils (c'est pas incompatible hein, on va pas faire de conflits familiaux :) ).